# Time complexity for nester for loop

Tags: time, complexity-theory

```
 for(int i =1; i<n; i=i*2)
 {
   for(int j=1; j<i; j++){
          printf("hello");
       }
    }
```

Is the time complexity O(logn) or O(nlogn)?

Answer (score 0):

It's neither. It's O(n).

First, study the special cases where n = 2^k-1 e.g. 1,3,7,15,31,63,127,255 ....
Second, for any number n, prove that if 2^(k-1) <= n < 2^k then  2^k - 1 <= 2n

that's all.

Comment: why O(n)? I mean the first loop is O(logn) right? then how can it be O(n)?

Comment: because the complexity for the special case where n = 2^k-1 is equal to 2^k -1 so your lower bound can't be lower than O(n)

Answer (score -1):

The time complexity for this will be O(n^2) [n square]

Comment: Wrong. read the outer loop carefully. It's  not a classic i = i +1